# How to convert Swift UIDatePicker to string and then check with another date

Tags: ios, string, swift, date, datepicker

I am trying to make a funny app called "Is It Your Birthday"
You essentially plug in your birth date, and then you plug in the current date, and it checks the two dates and responds with 
"Today is not your birthday..."
OR
"Today is your birthday!"

Simple enough app right?

I'm having problems though.. At this point I have simply made a constant called myBirthday (January 15th)

Then the user uses a UIDatePicker, and selects the current date.

The program checks the variable "dateChosen" from the DatePicker (Which I believe I have properly converted the day and month into a string) with the "myBirthday " constant

For some reason, even if I select January 15th (15-01), and check it with "myBirthday" (15-01), it does not recognize that these are the same dates!!

Can anyone help me!
Here is my code

Thanks :)
(This is all programmed in Swift by the way)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var responseText = "Response Text"
let myBirthday = "15-01"
var dateChosen = ""


@IBOutlet var checkButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var displayAnswer: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedDate: UILabel!

@IBAction func datePickerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM"

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
    var dateChosen = strDate
    println(strDate)
}



@IBAction func checkButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if dateChosen == myBirthday {
        displayAnswer.hidden = false
        responseText = "Today is your birthday!"
        self.displayAnswer.text = responseText
    } else {
        displayAnswer.hidden = false
        responseText = "Today is not your birthday..."
        self.displayAnswer.text = responseText
    }
}






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have both an instance variable `dateChosen` and a local variable of the same name in your `checkButtonClicked` method. The local variable hides the instance variable. Your code saves a value into the local variable and then that value is discarded when the function returns.

Get rid of the local variable `dateChosen` inside `checkButtonClicked`. That way the function will change the instance variable.

You should learn to use the debugger. You would have found this problem by stepping through your code.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Duncan! 

What would you suggest I do to start learning how to use the debugger? To learn swift right now I am reading through the swift programming manual, and it doesn't talk about Xcode much. Are there any sources you would recommend to start learning how to use the debugger?

Thanks for all your help!
You're awesome!

Kaleb.